# Video Streaming from iPhone to a Web application through a server

Tags: iphone, ios5, windows-server-2003, live-streaming

I want to stream the Video/Audio recorded by the iphone to the server and view the same video from a webapplication in real time.
Can anybody tell me how this can be achieved if its possible

Thanks in advance
Regards
Nitesh

Comment: The second part of the question is not really a concern. You want to know how to stream and upload video (simultaneously) to the server... right ?

Comment: This ain't the answer but a help http://www.tuaw.com/2009/08/15/streaming-video-from-your-iphone-they-crippled-the-app-for-that/

Answer (score 0):

`UStream` and `QIK` are two apps which serve your purpose.
Refer this link. It may be helpful:[LINK](http://singularityhub.com/2009/12/21/broadcast-streaming-video-iphone-finally-has-an-app-for-that/)

Comment: Hi i want something like an SDK to use in my application rather than a ready made application